# When do files get stored in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA when executing an .exe?

Tags: windows, electron, electron-builder, norton

My team is creating a Desktop application using Electron. During testing Norton flagged and blocked an action for accessing a file located in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA when running the application for the first time.

> **Activity**: Data Protector blocked a suspicious action by my-app.exe

> **Target**: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA

> **Action Observed**: Suspicious process attempted to open a file protected by Data Protector

I researched about this location and it is used to store certificate pair keys for the system and its users. Whenever a certificate request is generated for the machine, a new file is created in this location.

My question is why does starting the app trigger a certificate request? When do a certificate requests get generated? Does it get generated whenever a Microsoft executes a .exe file for the first time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.